# Default message for a chat bot

Tags: bots, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am using Microsoft Bot integrated to a web page via a Direct Line channel. I was wondering if I can change the default message on the chat bot "Type your message". Please see the attached image:

[image: Chat bot control]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set the send box placeholder message at the moment. There is currently a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1833) requesting the functionality that is being tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1839). Might be beneficial to leave a +1 on the placeholder issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please upvote it! Thanks!